# Execution of smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment, erc-20, tokens

Private sale/ presale/ main sale all these category are specified in different contract or all in one ?

Comment: Do more reasearch, this only depend to you.

Answer (score 2):

As someone already pointed out, it all depends on you.

You have a few options as I see it:

- Write it all in one contract which has different stages and switches between them automatically upon meeting certain requirements
- Write multiple contracts which are used for the same thing
- Do the logic off-chain so that you for example deploy a new contract for new stage or transition an existing contract with a call.

Comment: & is there any more specific system and  servers we needed to deployee the smart contract ? and is it necessary to download and run geth & download the whole ethereum blockchain in order to proceed can't get much info out

Comment: I believe Geth is the most popular option. But you don't have to use that. Check for example:
https://www.ethereum.org/token or 
https://guide.blockchain.z.com/en/docs/basic/helloworld/go-eth/